# Python lambda function fail to remove the substring in Series

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I was trying to remove substring that is within the parenthesis with replace and strip function

**Below code worked fine and can remove the substrings**

```
parenthesis = '\((.*?)\)'

df['first name'] = df['first name'].str.replace(parenthesis, '')

df['first name'] = df['first name'].str.strip(parenthesis)
```

Then i was experimenting with lambda function hoping to improve the speed. Yet below lambda with similar functionality as above fail to remove the substrings. Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
df['first name']= df['first name'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(parenthesis,''))
df['first name']= df['first name'].apply(lambda x: x.strip(parenthesis))
```

Comment: did you try to add `r` to your string like : `r'\((.*?)\)'` ?

Comment: `apply` gets text as normal object `string` which does't use regex. But `.str.` uses own functions to work with `string` and I think it should work better/faster then `apply` because it can use code in C/C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String replace in python does not support regex, use `re.sub` instead

```
df['first name'].apply(lambda x: re.sub('\((.*?)\)', '', x).strip())
```

Test:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'first name': ['some (name)', 'somename'] })
df['first name'] = df['first name'].apply(lambda x: re.sub('\((.*?)\)', '', x).strip())
print (df)
```

Output:

```
  first name
0       some
1   somename
```